# Println error using enumate paramer and import error

Tags: java, enumeration, println

I have an Enumeration class like this:

```
public enum Elementi {

        IDROGENO("H", 1, 1.008),
        ELIO("He", 2, 4.003),
        // ... altri elementi
        LITIO("Li", 3, 6.491);

        private int numeroAtomico;
        private double massaAtomica; 
        private String simbolo;

        public int getNumeroAtomico() {
            return numeroAtomico;
        }

        public String getSimbolo() {
            return simbolo;
        }

        private Elementi(String simbolo, int numeroAtomico, double massaAtomica){

            this.simbolo = simbolo;
            this.numeroAtomico = numeroAtomico;
            this.massaAtomica = massaAtomica;
        }
}
```

In another file i have a Main program like this:

```
import java.util.Elementi;

public class Main{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        for (Elementi e: Elementi.values())
            System.out.println("%s\t|\t%d|\t%s\n", e.getSimbolo(),e.getNumeroAtomico(), e);
    }
}
```

If i compile and execute both the two files i get the following errors:

```
-Main.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import java.util\\\.\\\Elementi;

symbol: class Elementi
location: package java.util

-Main.java:7: error: no suitable method found for println (String, String, int, Elementi)
                        System.out\\\.\\\println("%s\t|\t%d|\t%s\n", e.getSimbolo(), e.getNumeroAtomico(), e);

Method PrintStream.println(Object) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println(char[]) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println(double) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println(float) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println(long) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println(int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println(char) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println(boolean) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)
Method PrintStream.println() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in lenght)

2 errors
```

i put the two errors between \\ like this:
 \\error\\

I would fix these problems

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think your `Elementi` is in `java.util` package. import with the proper package.
2. `System.out.println()` doesn't take varargs and format string. Use `System.out.printf()` instead.